# Is it possible to type something into the address bar without going to the URL?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, url

On the desktop version of Safari, you can type something into the address bar without going to it. If I think of something I want to search as I'm browsing, I can put it in the address bar, but I won't press enter until I'm done reading the current page.

How do I do this on the iOS version of Safari? Typing something in the address bar gives you 2 options: "go" and "cancel." Unfortunately, pressing "cancel" will delete what you typed and revert the text in the address bar back to the original URL of the page you're on.

Is it possible to type something into the address bar on iOS Safari and leave it there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### This is technically impossible to achieve in the current version of iOS.

Though, you may want to try this trick which isn't right what you'd like to do, but may be a way around:

1. **Tap** the address bar and **type** whatever you want to search
2. **Copy** what you've just typed
3. Tap on **cancel** in order to get back to your current open webpage
4. When you're done and you want to search what you typed before, simply **long press** the address bar and tap on **Paste and Search**.

---

As I said before, this is not what you'd like to do, which indeed is not possible to achieve at the moment. Although, this may be an easy and quick trick as a way around of what you wanted to do.

Hope this helped you out!

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible in iOS Safari.